# Pycharm docker remote python interpreter

Tags: macos, python-3.x, docker, pycharm

When trying to configure a Remote Python Interpreter in Pycharm using Docker I get the following error:

> com.github.dockerjava.api.excepion.DockerClientException: Enabled TLS
>   verification (DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1) but certificate path
>   (DOCKER_CERT_PATH) '/Users/me/.docker/machine/machines/default'
>   doesn't exist.

I've $export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=0 but with no difference.
I've manually created '/Users/me/.docker/machine/machines/default' but with no joy.

I've deinstalled and reinstalled both Docker and Pycharm but still get the same error.

I'm on a Mac OSX 10.12.1
Pycharm 2016.3

Full disclosure: I use vagrant and virtual box on my mac too.

Any pointers would be appreciated.
Kevin

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it as follows:

Obtain `socat` (if not already installed)

e.g. `brew install socat`

Then: `socat TCP-LISTEN:2375,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-CONNECT:/var/run/docker.sock`

Then in pycharm/docker config:
Api URL: tcp://localhost:2375

Many thanks to the following found on:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-153973

Answer (score 1):

If you have been using docker-machine for Mac to support PyCharm or the "socat" hack to access Docker API - It is no longer necessary with PyCharm EAP (https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/) — You can set your remote debugger API_URL directly to: unix:/var/run/docker.sock (supporting debug mode, and the environment runs a lot faster, when not using VirtualBox).

There is a no-questions-asked 30 day trial of EAP before that update goes live (some time this month)